# ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ai-platform.versions.create) argument VERSION: Must be specified

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

When deploying a model to GCP Predict using Custom Prediction Routine, I'm getting this error:

`ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ai-platform.versions.create) argument VERSION: Must be specified.`

However, I do have the version specified like this:

```
!gcloud beta ai-platform versions create $VERSION_NAME_ \
    --model=$MODEL_NAME \
    --runtime-version=1.15 \
    --python-version=3.7 \
    --config=$CONFIG \
    --origin=gs://$BUCKET_NAME/$PROJECT_NAME/$VERSION_NAME/model/ \
    --package-uris=gs://$BUCKET_NAME/$PROJECT_NAME/$VERSION_NAME/$PACKAGE_NAME \
    --prediction-class predict.Predictor
```

Also, see image below:

[image]

I tried upgrading the sdk to the latest version, but still getting the same error. Version info:

[image]

**Update (Jan. 1st, 2021)**:

After wrapping the `VERSION_NAME_` python variable with curly braces, I got another error:
[image]

I then wrapped the `REGION` variable with curly braces too, but got this error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is because I didn't define the `MODEL_NAME` variable and once it's defined, the error is resolved.